# How to run write-host in C# and print it out

Tags: c#, powershell

I want to print out write-host result in C#, but it doesn't work. Can you point out where I got wrong? Thank you in advance.

```
private string testPowershell(string path)
{
    PowerShell ps = PowerShell.Create();
    var results = ps.AddScript("write-host $env:systemdrive").Invoke();
    var result = results[0];
    string output = result.ToString();
    ps.Commands.Clear();
    Console.WriteLine(output);
    return output;
}
```

Comment: ignore the parameter

Comment: Use `Write-Output` instead. `Write-Host` goes to the information stream, if you were to capture it's output you would do `Write-Host $env:systemdrive 6>&1` not sure if that is possible in C#

Comment: I'm not too familiar with C# but, you may need to swap that `write-host` to `write-output`. W-H does just that, writes to the host/console window. Where as W-O interprets the string as an object that can be passed down the pipeline

Comment: @santiago, beat me to it.

Comment: Thank you guys so much, it works now!!